# How to set height property for SPAN

Tags: css, height, html

I need to make following code stretchable with predefined height

```
<style>
.title{
   background: url(bg.gif) no-repeat bottom right;
   height: 25px;
}
</style>

<span class="title">This is title</span>
```

But since **span** is inline element, "height" property won't work.

I tried using **div** instead, but it will expand up to the width of upper element. And the width should be flexible.

What's a good solution for this?

Comment: You should use heading tags (h1, h2, h3, ...) for titles. It's more semantically correct.

Comment: Yes, you are right Pickels. Thanks everyone for your help. This is my final css. It works great for me: <style> h4 { 
  display: inline-block; 
  zoom: 1; 
  *display: inline; 
  margin: 0px; 
  height: 25px; 
 } </style>

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Give it a `display:inline-block` in CSS - that should let it do what you want.
In terms of compatibility: IE6/7 **will** work with this, as quirks mode suggests:

> IE 6/7 accepts the value only on elements with a natural display: inline.

Comment: For what it's worth, IE7 doesn't support `inline-block`.

Comment: Np. @Scott: I don't see that on W3 -- here's what they say: `Note: No versions of Internet Explorer (including IE8) support the property values "inline-table", "run-in", "table", "table-caption", "table-cell", "table-column", "table-column-group", "table-row", or "table-row-group".`

Comment: @henasraf - @Scott's correct, I can't use it because of quicks as well: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html

Comment: Quote: `IE 6/7 accepts the value only on elements with a natural display: inline.`

Comment: Another workaround is to maybe have a `padding-bottom:?` to it?

Comment: Ahah, I guess it will work if applied to a `span` then. Thanks for the info, henasraf.

Answer (score 27):

Use

```
.title{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 25px;
}
```

The only trick is browser support. [Check if your list of supported browsers handles inline-block here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#inlineblock).

Answer (score 13):

this is to make display:inline-block work in all browsers:

Quirkly enough, in IE (6/7) , if you trigger hasLayout with "zoom:1" and then set the display to inline, it behaves as an inline block.

```
.inline-block {
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you don't want to make it a block element, then you might try:

```
.title  {
    display: inline-block; /* which allows you to set the height/width; but this isn't cross-browser, particularly as regards IE < 7 */
    line-height: 2em; /* or */
    padding-top: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}
```

But the easiest solution is to simply treat the `.title` as a block-level element, and using the appropriate heading tags `<h1>` through `<h6>`.

Answer (score 0):

span `{ display: table-cell; height: (your-height + px); vertical-align: middle; }`

For spans to work like a table-cell (or any other element, for that matter), height must be specified. I've given spans a height, and they work just fine--but you must add height to get them to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Another option of course is to use Javascript (Jquery here):

```
$('.box1,.box2').each(function(){
    $(this).height($(this).parent().height());
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In some case you may want to adjust a SPAN height without changing display : inline.

To solve this, you can add a top and/or bottom border property, setting the required width parameter to your needs, and a transparent color to hide that border :

```
.myspan {
   border-top : solid 3px transparent;
   border-bottom : solid 3px transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.my-span {
    border: solid 1px;
    border-color: gray;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    height: 17px;
    padding-top: 6px;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 0px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Why do you need a span in this case? If you want to style the height could you just use a div? You might try a div with `display: inline`, although that might have the same issue since you'd in effect be doing the same thing as a span.

Comment: Or, ignore my ramblings altogether and use henasraf's answer :)

Comment: Down voting comments just discourages those who want to legitimately contribute. Stop it! Just offer some constructive feedback instead, or probably more to the point, your own opinion on the matter.