# Does height and width not apply to span?

Tags: css, html, width

Total noob question, but here.

CSS

```
.product__specfield_8_arrow {

    /*background-image:url(../../upload/orng_bg_arrow.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;*/
    background-color:#fc0;
    width:50px !important;
    height:33px !important;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    border-left:none;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    border-top-left-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;
    margin:0;
    padding:2px;
    cursor:pointer;
}​​​
```

HTML

```
<span class="product__specfield_8_arrow">&nbsp;</span>​
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fwbxU/)

Basically I'm trying to emulate a button, make a span (or something) look like a button next to an input field that actually doesn't need to be one because of an auto fill generator that generates errors onEnter. Thought this'd be a quick fix for now but obviously not.

Thanks.

Comment: You might also want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343989/how-to-set-height-property-for-span

Comment: Also check the standard, specifically http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-width-property and http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property, which state the properties "Applies to: all elements but non-replaced inline elements, table rows, and row groups"

Answer (score 542, accepted):

Span is an inline element. It has no width or height.

You could turn it into a block-level element, then it will accept your dimension directives.

```
span.product__specfield_8_arrow
{
    display: inline-block; /* or block */
}
```

Comment: Thanks, fixed it. I tried display:block before but inline block fixed it.

Comment: That's the problem. If `display: block` is specified, span stops to be an inline element and an element after it appears on next line. I need an element which is inline, but could be of desired width.

Comment: a better solution is to user display: inline-block

Comment: I love you from the future! (your post is more than 10 years old but helped me at this future time in relation to the date of post !), I love the past for bringing me brilliant answers. I love you!

Answer (score 40):

Try using a `div` instead of the `span` or using the CSS `display: block;` or `display: inline-block;`—`span` is by default an inline element which cannot take `width` and `height` properties.

Comment: a div is not a semantic replacement for a span. A span is a textual container whereas a div is a layout container. Applying an inline-block style like Developer Art has suggested is the correct answer.

Comment: The question provides no context to indicate that a div is inherently inappropriate semantically.

Comment: Actually, reading the op's markup it actually looks like the element in question is being used to simply display a background image. In this case a div would actually be more appropriate. -1 removed from Isaac's original comment.

Comment: Further, I tried to use a div before switching to span, it always displays under the previous div.. So went with Span :)

Answer (score 25):

Inspired from @Hamed, I added the following and it worked for me:

```
display: inline-block; overflow: hidden;
```

Answer (score 12):

Span takes width and height only when we make it block element.

```
span {display:block;}
```

Comment: I think `display: inline-block;` is better

Comment: Doing this way you will change for all the spans, I'd recommend using a class.

Answer (score 9):

As per comment from @Paul, If display: block is specified, span stops to be an inline element and an element after it appears on next line.

I came here to find solution to my span height problem and I got a solution of my own

Adding `overflow:hidden;` and keeing it inline will solve the problem just tested in IE8 Quirks mode

Comment: I keep seeing `overflow:hidden;` in this context. "Content is clipped, with no scrollbars" [says MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow). Seems counterintuitive. What does it do here?

Answer (score 8):

`span`s are by default displayed inline, which means they don't have a height and width.

Try adding a `display: block` to your span.

Answer (score 6):

Span starts out as an inline element.  You can change its display attribute to block, for instance, and its height/width attributes will start to take effect.

Answer (score 6):

Use this all problem solve way

**Try it..**

```
span.product__specfield_8_arrow
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`span {display:block;}` also adds a line-break.

To avoid that, use `span {display:inline-block;}` and then you can add width and height to the inline element, and you can align it within the block as well:

```
span {
        display:inline-block;
        width: 5em;
        font-weight: normal;
        text-align: center
     }
```

[more here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp)

Answer (score 0):

There are now multiple ways to mimic this same effect but further tailor the properties based on the use case. As stated above, this works:

```
.product__specfield_8_arrow { display: inline-block }
```

but also

```
.product__specfield_8_arrow { display: inline-flex } // flex container will be inline
.product__specfield_8_arrow { display: inline-grid } // grid container will be inline
.product__specfield_8_arrow { display: inline-table } // table will be inline-level table
```

This [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CSSBurner/mv497eg8/) shows how similar these display properties are in this case.

For a relevant discussion please see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24313271/display-property-differences-for-inline-something).

Answer (score 0):

The way I deal with this is to use a borderless, read-only input tag and then you can set the attributes as desired:

```
 <input  type="text" readonly 
   style="border:none; background-color: transparent; width:200px; margin-top:10px; padding-left: 10px;" 
      [value]="statusMessage">
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually span is an inline element. So height and width will not work but, if you have your span in a container and it has display flex then it will.

```html
div class
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.product__specfield_8_arrow {
  /*background-image:url(../../upload/orng_bg_arrow.png);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;*/
  background-color: #fc0;
  width: 50px !important;
  height: 33px !important;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-left: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="product__specfield_8_arrow">&nbsp;</span>

  </span>
</div>
```