# Fixed width for <a>

Tags: html, css

I have 3 `<a>` selectors in my `<div>`. I gave them fixed widths. But they are not stretching to correct widths. They are just stretching to fit to their containing data (texts). But I want them to divide my parent div to 3 cells and I want them to fill it using the assigned widths.

I am attaching an image below. the first image shows what I am getting now and the second image shows what I what.

[image]

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/j6kcJ/1/)** is the fiddle.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does height and width not apply to span?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491068/does-height-and-width-not-apply-to-span)

Comment: Those are not selectors. Those are elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use:    `display:inline-block;`

[jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j6kcJ/2/)

also : use percents !

http://jsfiddle.net/j6kcJ/4/

latest :

http://jsfiddle.net/j6kcJ/5/

Comment: this is useful, but how can I remove space in between them??

Comment: I think float-left is enough to do the work with percentages. Am I wrong??

Comment: float left is to take it to the most left , and percentage is to divide the with to be as you want. . you can also use fixed with if you measure it accurately

Answer (score 1):

Give the anchor elements a display value of inline-block and the width values will apply to them.

Answer (score 1):

Just need to add this css style:

```
.xxx a {display:inline-block;float:left;}
```

Hope this helps