# What element is preventing my width attribute being applied to my tabs?

Tags: html, css, tabs, width, styling

I'm completely new to HTML, CSS and Javascript but drawing on previous knowledge of typical programming from Java and C along with numerous tutorials and google searches I've been piecing together a very rough image of how this all works.

Now something that is driving me crazy is I recently added a tabbed content box into my website, one that is on the main page that allows you to select one of 4 different paragraphs by clicking on the appropriate tab. I pulled it off of a tutorial and have a basic understanding of how its working.. but for some reason I cannon get it to let me adjust the width of each of these tabs..

Here is the `html` for the tabs:

```
<div id="feature-tabs">
    <ul id="tabs">
        <li><a href="#What We Do">What We Do</a></li>
        <li><a href="#What Makes Us Different">What Makes Us Different</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Our Background">Our Background</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Why We Do It">Why We Do It</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>`
```

And here is the associated `CSS` that styles it.

```
#feature-tabs {
    height: 16px;
    width: 150px;
}

ul#tabs {
     list-style-type: none; 
     margin: 0 0 2 0; 
}
    ul#tabs li {
        float: left;
    }
        ul#tabs li a {
            color: #42454a; 
            background-color: #dedbde; 
            border: 1px solid #c9c3ba; 
            border-bottom: none; 
            text-decoration: none;
            width: 150px;
        }
            ul#tabs li a:hover {
                background-color: #f1f0ee;
            }
            ul#tabs li a.selected {
                color: #000; 
                background-color: #f1f0ee; 
                font-weight: bold;
            }
```

I need this very much so for the look I'm going for but I simply cannot find out why no matter where I put `width: ___px;` it just won't apply.

I am wondering if there is something I'm doing which prevents width from being an applicable trait or what have you.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it work if you write the styles in-line: `<li style="width: 150px">`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this style:

```
ul#tabs li a {
    // ..
    display: block;
}
```

- [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/aLeq9/)

This happens because `a` is an inline element by default. Inline elements don't react to height/width.

- [Does height and width not apply to span?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491068/does-height-and-width-not-apply-to-span)
- [The Width Property<sup>w3</sup>](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-width-property)

Comment: Okay it actually works combining your answer, Joseph Silber's along with adding an additional width constraint to the ul#tabs li a {} tag to fill the box out completely. Much Appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Add the following rule to your link :

```
ul#tabs li a { display: inline-block; }
```

Comment: Tested in IE 7, can't get hold of an IE 6 copy though... IE7 works though... The tags for this question is HTML5 and CSS3 which kinda throws the older browsers out of the ball game (fort his question)