# CSS nested spans and width attribute

Tags: css, nested, width, html

I have a question on nested spans and how CSS applies the width attribute.  The HTML is like this, the 'wide' class sets the width.  The box class gives it a border.  Width gets applied only if I have wide and box together.  Can someone explain to me why this is the case?  I am CSS amateur, maybe this is some basic rule that I missed.

```
<span class="wide"><span  class="box">Not wide</span></span>
<span class="wide box"><span>Wide</span></span>
<span><span class="wide box">Wide</span></span>
<span class="box"><span class="wide">Not wide</span></span>
```

You can see the effect here:
http://jsfiddle.net/7hXUu/2/

Thanks for any insight,
Aaron

Comment: [a possible answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491068/does-height-and-width-not-apply-to-span)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is using `float:left;`. But i don't know what exactly cuases this.

You may apply the width for elements like `span, a` by using `display:block;` or `display:inline-block;`

Comment: You guys are fast, thanks! Adding display:block; to wide class fixes last case, adding 'width:inherit' to box class fixes first case.

Answer (score 1):

[Widths cannot be applied to inline elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-width), however rendering behaviour is different for f[loated inline elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#float-width):

> If `'width'` is computed as `'auto'`, the used value is the
>   "shrink-to-fit" width... Then the shrink-to-fit width is:
>   `min(max(preferred minimum width, available width), preferred width)`

That's not all. Your floating container spans each establish new [block formatting contexts](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting), affecting the calculated results of [floated element positioning](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#float-position). I could probably go over it step-by step if there were enough requests, but this is definitely an unpractical scenario.

Bottom line is: this is good spaghetti code for a brain-teaser question, but horrible for real-life use.

Answer (score -1):

The `box` class has `float: left`, turning the element to a floated element, as opposite to the default for `span`, an inline element. The `width` property does not apply to inline elements.

Another way of making `width` apply to a `span` element is to set `display: inline-block` on it.