# Dynamically change CSS style height

Tags: jquery, html, css, angular

I am making users' leaderbord:

```
 <div class="user">
  <ul id="jogadores" *ngFor="let u of sortedUsers$; let i=index;" (click)="routeToUser(u.id)">
    <li class="user">
      <img class="gravatar" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{u.imgUrl}}?d=https://www.1plusx.com/app/mu-plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack-pro/images/default-user-image.png" />
      <div class="progressBar">
        <span style="height: 100%;">
          <i></i>
          <b>{{sortedUsers$[i].points}}</b>

        </span>
      </div>
      <span class="username">
        <strong>{{sortedUsers$[i].username}}</strong>
      </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Each `<ul>` element has some values which are coming from array. All evening I've been trying to change `<span style="height: 100%;">` value to some value from `{{sortedUsers$[i].points}}` so each progress bar would change according to how many points user has. I tried passing value:

```
<span style="height: {{sortedUsers$[i].points}} %;">
```

also reaching it with jQuery, but also failed.

Comment: did `<span style="height: 100px;">` work ? if not change the display to block or inline-block

Comment: Yes it works, but what I need is to change value 100 to whatever comes  in the loop and this doesn't work. like for element[1] it has to be 80, for  element[1] 20 and so on

Comment: Have you already made span as a block or inline-block element ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [ngStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle)

> Update an HTML element styles.

```
<span [ngStyle]="{'height': `${sortedUsers$[i].points}%`}"></span>
```

Your value would look like the following, where each number represent a `percent: sortedUsers$[i].points = 100 // Percent`

Answer (score 2):

Height and width cannot be applied to `span`.

You can make it `block element` or `inline-block` and then it will accept your height and width.

Read more here: [Does height and width not apply to span?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491068/does-height-and-width-not-apply-to-span/37876264)

Comment: `inline-block` is more appropriate for spans (since are usually used as contextual wrapping inline elements) - whereas `div` are best suited for a  *DIVisor* block element.

Comment: That can be decided as per the need but i have updated the answer to give more clearity:)

Answer (score 2):

I dont know if you noticed but you have a space between `{{sortedUsers$[i].points}}` and `%;` it should be like this with no space

```
<span style="height: {{sortedUsers$[i].points}}%;">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use style attribute binding

```
<span [style.height]="sortedUsers$[i].points">
    <i></i>
   <b>{{sortedUsers$[i].points}}</b>
</span>
```

Where the value can be this `sortedUsers$[i].points = "100%"`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your help! What worked for me was:

```
 <span class="user" [ngStyle]="{ 'height': getPoints(i)}">
          <i></i>
          <b>{{sortedUsers$[i].points}}</b>
  </span>
```

with:

```
getPoints(id) {
return this.sortedUsers$[id].points + '%';}
```

I am pretty sure some of yours would have worked either, but just letting you all know if someone gets similiar problem later! Such an easy thing got me stuck for hours! Thank you all!

Comment: You could also use a template string for neater syntax, in my personal opinion: `getPoints(id) {
return \`${this.sortedUsers$[id].points}%\`;}`