# How to fix fluid div tag when javascript is loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

First of all I am sorry  not providing a better title that can clearly describe my problem.Here is my problem I have the following block of code which is creating a label for displaying time to my user.

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="container">
     <div class="card">
       <div class="card-header" data-background-color="purple">
         <h4 class="title"><h3 class="title"><span id="countdown" class="timer"></span></h3></h4>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Time is being displayed between the `span` element using JavaScript, now the problem is that, when JavaScript is loading time for the first time after every page refresh, the label displaying time become  half it's usual size  because the `span` tag is empty.I need the display label to maintain the same height regardless of whether there is content or not, inside  `span` tag.Anyone who can help me fix this?Forgive my English.

Comment: Please provide the Javascript and CSS as well so we can recreate the issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set height property for SPAN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343989/how-to-set-height-property-for-span)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a default value inside the `<span>`. You could write `loading...`, `00:00` or put an `&nbsp;`.

Comment: @Soviut-This one nailed it,exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps drop in a non-breaking space `&nbsp;` inside the `<span>`, so that there is something for the browser to pick up on. It can be safely replaced with your time after Javascript is ready to start up.

Answer (score 0):

Why not put something meaningful in the span for accessibility, but set it to `opacity: 0;` for display purposes, then when the span is updated and ready to display, set it to `opacity: 1;`. Hiding something with `opacity` (or `visibility: hidden;`) will maintain layout on the page.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  var cd = document.getElementById('countdown');
  cd.innerHTML = 'ready';
  cd.classList.add('ready');
},1000)
```

```css
.timer {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s;
}
.ready {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<h4 class="title"><h3 class="title"><span id="countdown" class="timer">Loading</span></h3></h4>
```